# Is it possible add/remove pin marker on location plan(image or vector) by using Javascript or DevExpress?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

There are nearly 1000 cameras in the factory where I work. What I asked for is to mark the locations of these cameras on the map(non-geographical) of the factory. And by clicking on one of the camera icons by zooming, it is necessary to connect to the camera with a IP address and instantly watch the camera in the popup.

After long research, I couldn't get enough information for me. In the sources I have researched, latitude and longitude operations are made on the real map. But since I do not know the latitude and longitude values of the cameras, I cannot do this way. Which technology or which library can I use for this requirement? I searched a lot and I could not reach the necessary information. I am curious about your opinion on the subject.

Comment: The DevExtreme HTML5/JS map widget can display vector floor maps. See: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/VectorMap/FloorPlan/jQuery/Light/

Comment: Of course I examined the Floor Plan. But I have a plan already drawn in jpg format. It is very costly and not necessary to draw again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I can find is like the link below. [ZoomMarker](https://github.com/NoticeVengus/ZoomMarker)